# How to set PIDFile for systemd when main process start multiple child and exit?

Tags: server, daemon, systemd

Environment: Ubuntu 16.04, daemon programmed in c, using systemd for process management.

So i have the unit file as:

```
[Unit]
Description=Fantastic Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Restart=always
Type=forking
ExecStart=/opt/fan/tastic

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And in my tastic.c code, it basically fork() X number of childs each doing so_reuseport, and than the main process exits leaving the childs to handle requests.

With the above setup it works fine, and i get the expected behavior.

However if i put the PIDFile in the service unit file, i get that the pid provided by my application is non-existent, which it is - since my main process is exiting after starting up the requested number of childs.

Now in the systemd documentation it clearly states that if you do Type=forking you should provide the PIDFile, but the issue is that how am i supposed to provide a single pid file when there are multiple childs and the main parent process exits once the childs start?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you found, the system works fine without `PIDFile=` in your case. The docs *recommend* the use of `PIDFile=`, but I believe that's for the case when there is a single main process, which doesn't apply to your case.

Also see [`man systemd.kill`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html) which explains how processes will be killed. The default is "control-group", which kills "all remaining processes in the control group".

So by default, `systemd` is going to clean up all those child processes at  "stop" time for you, which is what you want.

For someone who *did* have a main process, they might want to use `KillMode=process`, and in that case setting `PIDFile=` may help with that, but this does not apply to your case.